# How to programmatically assign new product to default category?

Tags: php, magento

Since

```
Mage::app()->getWebsite(true)->getDefaultStore()->getRootCategoryId();
```

returns `'2'` I've wrote

```
$productCatalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$productCatalog->setCategoryIds('2')->save();
```

but it doesn't change product's category - in Categories tab checkbox "Default Category" isn't ticked.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a product called $product and a category ID called $category_id

You can put it into a category by doing the following

```
$product->setCategoryIds(array($category_id));
$product->save();
```

Comment: `$productCatalog->setCategoryIds(array(2));` doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, you enclosing category id inside a single quote. The method expect an integer array as its parameter. So try this

```
$category_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite(true)->getDefaultStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$productCatalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$productCatalog->setCategoryIds(array($category_id));
$productCatalog->save();
```

Comment: it should work. Because I have tested it in my magento environment

Comment: `$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();`

Comment: are you sure your `productCatalog` holds a product ?

Comment: sure, `var_dump($productCatalog)` resturns huge `object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)` that almost kills my browser

Comment: ok try `var_dump(productCatalog->getCategoryIds())` and look whether it holds any data ?

Comment: before `setCategoryIds` it returns empty array, after - array with a single string("2")

Comment: `$product` is ok, other operations like `setName()` or `setStatus()` work

Comment: ok then you try this one `$product->getCategoryIds()`. Tell me whether it returns any data

Comment: `var_dump($product->getCategoryIds())` returns empty array

Comment: `<catalog_product_new_action>`

Comment: Why do you trying to save a product for `new` action. I think that may be the problem